# Output a linux command to a url/port or scocket instead of writing it to a file

Tags: linux, sockets, websocket, pipe

I have a command which out outputs certain data which i store in a ext file using a '>>' command.Now Instead of doing that I want to have a socket or a port on any server which will catch the output of the command.Basically i want to output all my script data to a socket or url which ever is possible.

Any help in this direction is most welcomed.

Comment: You can save it to a file, but make some script which will send data to a server by "curl" and rotate file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use socat to listening on a port 12345 and echo any data sent to it like this:

```
socat -u TCP-LISTEN:12345,keepalive,reuseaddr,fork STDOUT
```

If you want to capture it to a file as well (`file.log`), you can use the same command with tee:

```
socat -u TCP-LISTEN:12345,keepalive,reuseaddr,fork STDOUT | tee file.log
```

You can run your program to output to bash's TCP virtual device:

```
./prog > /dev/tcp/localhost/12345
```

If you don't want to use bash magic then you can also use socat to send the data:

```
./prog | socat - TCP-CONNECT:localhost:12345
```

The above example assume you are running your program and "logger" on the same system but you can replace "localhost" with the hostname or address of the system you wish to send to (where the socat is listening).

Comment: I am upvoting this one because it works perfectly as required also this one is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @jision You should consider accepting this answer as well, if this works for you.